# DialogFragment attaches to MainActivity instead of parent fragment activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, dialogfragment

I create a DialogFragment from a Fragment and I have implemented a listener in the fragment, the problem is that the DialogFragment attaches to MainActivity instead of Parent Frame.

So I have this code in the DialogFragment which is called from the Fragment

```
// Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the
// SensorRateChangeListener
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the SensorRateChangeListener so we can send events to
        // the host
        mListener = (SensorRateChangeListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement SensorRateChangeListener");
    }
}
```

And this is the code from Fragment which calls the dialog

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
            if (prev != null) {
                ft.remove(prev);
            }
            ft.addToBackStack(null);

            // Create and show the dialog.
            DialogFragment newFragment = SensorRateChangeDlg.newInstance(mStackLevel);
            newFragment.show(ft, "rate");
```

And when I run the app and the DialogFragment is created it crashes with the error....MainActivity should implement SensorRateChangeListener, but it is implemented in the calling Fragment.

```
Error: MainActivity@424085b8 must implement SensorRateChangeListener
```

I cannot implement the SensorRateChangeListener interface in MainActivity, because it have a lot of other functions related to the Fragment and it would make things more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your app crashes here

```
 mListener = (SensorRateChangeListener) activity;
```

because it's expecting your Main Activity to be like this:

```
public class MainAcivity extends Activity implements SensorRateChangeListener{
```

since you implemented the **SensorRateChangeListener** interface in another fragment, it crashed.
so just implement the **SensorRateChangeListener** interface in MainActivity or just implement a method like this:

```
public void setOnSensorRateChangeListener(SensorRateChangeListener listener){
mListener=listener;
}
```

### EDIT

and from the activity/fragment that implements the **SensorRateChangeListener** interface:

```
newFragment.setOnSensorRateChangeListener(this);
```

then check if the listener is not null before calling it:

```
if(mListener!=null)
```

Comment: You're right, but where should I call the setOnSensorRateChangeListener?

Comment: In your Activity after creating a new instance of the fragment

Comment: In MainActivity? or in the FragmentActivity which calls the DialogFragment?

Comment: It depends on the class that implements the interface and hold the DialogFragment, it can be the MainActivity or the FragmentActivity, please check the updated answer above

Comment: In fragment, but what parameters should I pass to setOnSensorRateChangeListener?

Comment: Now I have this, but it crashes

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                SensorRateChangeDlg dialogFragment = new SensorRateChangeDlg();
                dialogFragment.setOnSensorRateChangeListener(this);
                dialogFragment.show(fm, "rate");

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can not set Dialog's OnCancelListener or OnDismissListener

Comment: This is an another issue, I suggest posting it in a separate question and posting your code.

Comment: but the problem is still related to this question, I have not solved this problem with the FragmentDialog Listener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69070/discussion-between-mina-samy-and-mario-m).